# Personal Access Token - Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-passport

When I generate the access token through a login, I assign an expiration period (Short of 10 minutes) but later when those 10 minutes have passed the token is still valid (At least in my case).

**Is this normal? Shouldn't I receive an authentication error? Or do I have to do it manually in each method (API path)?**

I have this code in AuthServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));
}
```

Also in the Login I have this also just in case, but nothing ..

```
$user = $request->user();
$tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
$token = $tokenResult->token;
$token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an expiration time for Personal Access Tokens you should use the following method:

```
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinute());
```